# Using ssh fingerprint in ssh2-sftp-client

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, node-red, ssh2-sftp

Ok, this might need a little bit of explaination up front.

I am currently working on an automation project using [node-red](https://nodered.org/).
I want to upload and download files from an remote server using ssh. For this tasks I use [this](https://github.com/fatoldsun00/node-red-contrib-sftpco/) node-red package called `node-red-contrib-sftpc`. I rewrote the library a little bit, so that I can hand over some credentials for the sftp connection, via the payload which is handed over to the node.
To establish an connection the `sftp.connect` method of the [ssh2-sftp-client](https://github.com/theophilusx/ssh2-sftp-client#sec-5-2-2) is used:

```
await sftp.connect({ 
    host: node.server.host,
    port: node.server.port,
    username: node.server.username,
    password: node.server.password});
```

There you can find in the documentation that you can provide `connect` with the parameters `hostHash` and `hostVerifier`. The [documentation of the ssh2 model](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2), on which the ssh2-sftp-client is based, states that:

> **hostHash** - string - Any valid hash algorithm supported by node. The host's key is hashed using this algorithm and passed to the hostVerifier function as a hex string. Default: (none)
>
> **hostVerifier** - function - Function with parameters (hashedKey[,
> callback]) where hashedKey is a string hex hash of the host's key for
> verification purposes. Return true to continue with the handshake or
> false to reject and disconnect, or call callback() with true or false
> if you need to perform asynchronous verification. Default:
> (auto-accept if hostVerifier is not set)

So here is my problem: How do I write the `hostVerifier` function? I want to pass `hashedKey` and also `fingerprint`, so that I can return `true` or `false`, when the handshake worked out or not.
I want to check, if the given server key fingerprint is the "right" one and that I connect to the correct server.

So far as I understood the second parameter, will be a callback function, but I do not know how to use that, so that it will verify the handshake.
This was my try, or at least how I tried to do it.

```
node.server.hostVerifier = function (hashedKey, (hashedKey, msg.fingerprint)=> {
  if (hashedKey = msg.fingerprint) return true;
  else return false
  }){};

await sftp.connect({ 
    host: node.server.host,
    port: node.server.port,
    username: node.server.username,
    password: node.server.password,
    hostHash: 'someHashAlgo',
    hostVerifier: node.server.hostVerifier,});
```

I know that this is completely wrong, but I am about to get crazy, because I have no idea, how to proper check the ssh host key fingerprint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a solution myself and want to share it with you.
I defined an arrow function as the `hostVerifier` function, which takes implicite the value of the fingerprint through the `msg.fingerprint` variable. I only do this, if `node.server.fingerprint` has an value. So if I do not have an fingerprint at hand, the connection will still established.

```
node.server.fingerprint = msg.fingerprint;
if(!!node.server.fingerprint){
    node.server.hostHash = 'md5';
    node.server.hostVerifier =  (hashedKey) => {
            return (hashedKey === msg.fingerprint) ;};
    node.server.algorithms = {serverHostKey: ['ssh-rsa'],};
        };
```

For that I also declare my `node.server.alogrithms`. With that it was a little bit of try and error.

So I put everything together here:

```
await sftp.connect({ 
                host: node.server.host,
                port: node.server.port,
                username: node.server.username,
                password: node.server.password,
                hostHash: node.server.hostHash,
                hostVerifier: node.server.hostVerifier, 
                algorithms: node.server.algorithms,
                });
```